# Running a function n times with incrementally different arguments in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a simple Haskell function that computes a specific type of sum:

```
usum :: Integral a => [a] -> a -> a
usum (x:xs) max = sum (nub [num*k | num <- (x:xs), k <- [1..div max num]])
```

How can I run this function *n* times where `x:xs` is kept constant but `max` gets incremented by +1 as it goes from 1 to some upper limit?

If `usum` was implemented in an object-oriented language like Java I would do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
   System.out.println(usum(i));
}
```

How can an equivalent of this for loop be achieved in Haskell?

Comment: Unrelated: you should not be using the pattern `(x:xs)` above unless you also want to define another case for `[]`. Use `xs` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a list comprehension for `usum` to iterate on all values of `k`. You can use a similar approach to iterate on `n` as well:

```
foo xs n = [usum xs m | m <- [1..n]]
```

Answer (score 4):

The counter can be implemented by a list `[1..n]`. The loop body can be implemented using the `map` function. Combine both and you get:

```
f xs n = map (usum xs) [1..n]
```

Output:

```
> f [1,2,3] 10
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]
```